# imagemagick: follow orientation from exif data

Tags: imagemagick

About the ImageMagick command bellow:

```
imagemagick\convert.exe original.jpg -resize 100x400^ -gravity Center -crop 100x400+0+0 -sharpen 0x0.75 -quality 98% thumbnail.jpg
```

Some thumbnails generated (in a batch proccess) are not following the original's EXIF data. So they are being generated with the wrong angle. (+|- 90°)

Is there a way to command IM to read the exif data before converting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the [-auto-orient](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient) option.

> This operator reads and resets the EXIF image profile setting
>   'Orientation' and then performs the appropriate 90 degree rotation on
>   the image to orient the image, for correct viewing.

**Example**

```sh
convert original.jpg -auto-orient -resize 100x400^ \
        -gravity Center -crop 100x400+0+0 \
        -sharpen 0x0.75 -quality 98% \
        thumbnail.jpg
```